# Django Model Meta Ordering on Property

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to tell Django to order my Host model based on a property but am getting the following error:

```
app.Host: (models.E015) 'ordering' refers to the nonexistent field, related field, or lookup 'primary_hostname'.
```

What's the correct approach to ordering based on a property like this?  I want the queryset to be ordered by primary hostname which I define as the shortest hostname assigned to each host.

**models.py**

```
class Hostname(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=settings.MAX_CHAR_COUNT, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)

class Host(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    names = models.ManyToManyField(Hostname)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['primary_hostname']

    @property
    def primary_hostname(self):
        return self.names.annotate(text_len=Length('name')).order_by('text_len').first()

    def __str__(self):
        return "[Host object: id = {}]".format(self.id)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "[Host object: id = {}]".format(self.id)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Host):
            return self.id == other.id
        return False

    def __hash__(self) -> int:
        return hash(self.id)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.id < other.id

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return '/host/{}'.format(self.id)
```

Comment: is there any field with the name primary_hostname in the Host model?

Comment: @Sumithran nope

Comment: then that's the issue, replace it with a valid field_name

Comment: I don't want it to be a field name.  I want it to remain a property because it is a derived value.

Comment: I'm afraid that you can only order a query with field_names, not properties!!